# Identify all queries that target a given table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Is there a good way to identify all queries that target a given table (extended events, procedure cache, etc)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do it is to use the [SQL Server Audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) functionality. There's an example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/create-a-server-audit-and-database-audit-specification?view=sql-server-ver15#TsqlProcedure) which I'll reproduce slightly modified in case the link goes dead in the future:

The server audit defines where you want the log file to be:

```
USE master ;  
GO  
-- Create the server audit.   
CREATE SERVER AUDIT Payrole_Security_Audit  
    TO FILE ( FILEPATH =   
'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA' ) ;   
GO  
-- Enable the server audit.   
ALTER SERVER AUDIT Payrole_Security_Audit   
WITH (STATE = ON) ;
```

The database level audit lets you pick specific objects, operations, and users:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012 ;   
GO  
-- Create the database audit specification.   
CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION Audit_Pay_Tables  
FOR SERVER AUDIT Payrole_Security_Audit  
ADD (SELECT , INSERT , UPDATE, DELETE 
     ON HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory BY public)   
WITH (STATE = ON) ;   
GO
```

The "public" user should catch queries from anyone.

Answer (score -3):

sp_blitzcache @SlowlySearchPlansFor ([First Responder Kit](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit)) appears to be an another way of doing this as well.